# Convert Apache rewrite rules for lighttpd

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

I want to convert the following `.htaccess` rules to lighttpd rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/.*$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/_)|(error\.html)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

I don't have experience with lighttpd, but I need to start script on lighttpd server. How do I convert these rules andwhere do I need to place them so the script works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by this:

```
#/mnt/sdcard/pws/rewrite.conf

# rewrite rules
url.rewrite-if-not-file += (
    "^images/.*$" => "index.php",
    "^([^\?]+)(?:\?(.*))$" => "index.php?_route_=$1&$2",
    "^.*$" => "index.php"
)
# //rewrite rules
```